# Here's to the next great adventure, Michael Gambon

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Michael Gambon, most remembered in the SFF community for his portrayal of Albus Dumbledore in the Harry Potter film franchise, has [passed away this morning at age 82.](https://www.bbc.com/news/entertainment-arts-39408742)

While Michael may have been loud once when he should spoken softly, my favorite line from Dumbledore has always been

> To the well-organized mind, death is but the next great adventure.

So with great sadness I wish Michael the best of times on his next great adventure, for surely he did indeed have a well-organized mind. I know he will be missed by myself, members of the Wizarding World community, and our prayers are with his family and friends.

Comment: He asked, calmly

Comment: Many many great performances, but I highly recommend in particular _Maigret_, a TV series of mysteries where he's the detective Jules Maigret.

Comment: Everyone is talking about Dumbledore, but let's have a shout-out to his performance in the 2010 Doctor Who Christmas special, one of the best Eleventh Doctor stories. ***"We've had so many Christmas Eves, Kazran. I think it's time for Christmas Day."*** (I tried to find a gif of him and Abigail flying through the sky in the final scene, but couldn't find one online.)

Comment: Let's not forget his visit to Top Gear. It was so epic, they named a corner of their test track in his honor!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I imagine he has boarded a train and gone "on".

[image]